# Copy certain values from one element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to copy the width and height attributes from one element to another with JavaScript/jQuery but can't implement it.

I have something like that:

```
<div id="two">

<img src="picture.jpg" id="one" width="600px" height="300px" />

</div>
```

and I want to get this:

```
<div id="two" width="600px" height="300px" >

<img src="picture.jpg" id="one" width="600px" height="300px" />

</div>
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), and what went wrong?

Comment: Why do you have `px` in those attributes? They aren't CSS properties, they don't take CSS lengths.

Comment: I made an answer to your explicit question but usually you shouldn't have to do this. You should have a css that make it useless to duplicate those dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `.width` and `.height` properties of the image element directly.

Divs don't have those properties, so you have to use CSS to set them:

```
var img = $('#one').get(0);
$('#two').css({ width: img.width, height: img.height });
```

Answer (score 3):

With jquery :

```
var $one = $('#one');
$('#two').attr('width', $one.attr('width'))
.attr('height', $one.attr('height'));
```

But usually that's wrong. You should have a css that adapts the div to your image.

Comment: Superb, it works. (I want to do it this way because I can't make changes on the css and html files). Thank's for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, without greater information:

```
var el = $('#two'),
    img = el.find('img');

el.css({'height' : img.height(), 'width' : img.width()});
```

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/).
- [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Comment: I can't understand your code...anyway the dystroy's solution works for me. Thanks.

Comment: Seriously? Um, if you can highlight the parts you don't understand I'll happily try and explain. But it seems to be exactly the way that dystroy's answer works, albeit I'm styling with CSS (and using `css()`), instead of deprecated attributes.